# Making insert/update script work from orders one at a time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that 'works' but I had an oversight in logic and I'm trying to rectify it.

Basically, the below script selects orders from a db2 database, and every item on each order. What I'm doing is adding date intervals to the products for a time period that we believe that product to be on shelves. A customer should only have a number of records for any individual prodcut that's equal to number of stores they have, within the expiration window.

An example: If I'm customer 123 and I have 5 stores. Today I placed an order for skus 1,2, and 3 and I bought 2 of each. That's 2 records per product. Tomorrow I order 6 more of each product; that should add 3 records per product, and then overwrite the oldest records for those products 3 times and update the expiration date to one additional day. So within 2 days I placed multiple orders for the same 3 products, but the piece count was more than my number of stores so that's where the update comes in. At the end of the day, for any individual sku within an expiration window I should never have more records for each sku than number of locations.

Anyway, this works in terms of inserting, and it works for updates IF the record already exists when I do the select. But my problem is this: If the select has an order from yesterday and today, both of which containing items that should be updated, it's only going to select them all and insert because at the time of selecting, they didn't exist.

My solution to this in my mind is to break this up and process the script in a batch by order number, so that way I'm only inserting records for one order number, then going back and selecting the next order and doing it again. This way, every order number has the opportunity to be selected so that I can accurately determine if it needs to be updated or inserted. I feel like this should be fairly simple but I just don't know the best way to go about it.

Basically, I would select my order numbers, check my destination table for the items, then insert/update, then do it all again for the next order number, rather than selecting an array of order numbers and just working from that which could result in too many records being inserted rather than updated.

I can clarify if needed, but any help is much appreciated.

```
<?php

//Select orders from DB2 side
$detailStatCheck = "
        SELECT 
             inv as INVOICE,
             stat as STATUS,
             cust AS CUSTOMER,
             frm AS BODY,
             cov AS MTRL,
             col AS ATTR ,
             shpdte AS SHIPPED,
             qty AS QUANTITY,
             p.stores as STORES
        FROM goods g
        inner join plant p on g.cust = p.cstno
        WHERE to_date(char(shpdte), 'YYYYMMDD') >= '2018-01-01'
    ";

    //prepare and execute to select orders
    try {
        $detailCheck = $DB2conn->prepare($detailStatCheck);
        $detailRslt = $detailCheck->execute();
        $count2 = $detailCheck->fetch();
        print_r($count2);
    } catch(PDOException $ex) {
        echo "QUERY FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage();
    }


    //Create prepared INSERT statement
    $insertPlacement = "
        INSERT ignore INTO placedOrders (sku, category, CUSTOMER_id, start_date, expire_date, locations, order_num)
        SELECT 
            id, 
            category, 
            :CUSTOMER, 
            DATE_ADD(:SHIPPED),INTERVAL 7 DAY) as start_date,
            DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT(:SHIPPED, CHAR(20)), '%Y-%m-%d'),INTERVAL 127 DAY) as expire_date, 
            :STORES,
            :INVOICE  
        FROM sku s  
        WHERE  s.BODY=:BODY AND s.MTRL1=:MTRL AND s.ATTR1=:ATTR
    ";

    //check for existing records that are expired, which would trigger insert
    $expiredCheck = "
        SELECT 
            sku,
            CUSTOMER_id,
            expire_date
        FROM placedOrders p
            INNER JOIN sku s
                ON p.sku = s.id
        WHERE p.CUSTOMER_id = :CUSTOMER
            AND   s.BODY = :BODY
            AND   s.MTRL1 = :MTRL
            AND   s.ATTR1 = :ATTR
            AND   p.expire_date <= current_date()
    ";

    //check for existing records that are not expired, triggering update
    $validCheck = "
        SELECT 
            sku,
            CUSTOMER_id,
            expire_date
        FROM placedOrders p
            INNER JOIN sku s
                ON p.sku = s.id
        WHERE p.CUSTOMER_id = :CUSTOMER
            AND   s.BODY = :BODY
            AND   s.MTRL1 = :MTRL
            AND   s.ATTR1 = :ATTR
            AND   p.expire_date > current_date()
    ";

//prepare all update and insert queries
$checkExisting = $MysqlConn->prepare($expiredCheck);
$checkExistingValid = $MysqlConn->prepare($validCheck);
$insert = $MysqlConn->prepare($insertPlacement);
$update = $MysqlConn->prepare($updatePlacement);

    //while we have results from the order selection
    while ($row2 = $detailCheck->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $executionValues = [
            ":CUSTOMER" => $row2["CUSTOMER"],
            ":SHIPPED" => $row2["SHIPPED"],
            ":STORES" => $row2["STORES"],
            ":QUANTITY" => $row2["QUANTITY"],
            ":INVOICE" => $row2["INVOICE"],
            ":BODY" => $row2["BODY"],
            ":MTRL" => $row2["MTRL"],
            ":ATTR" => $row2["ATTR"],
        ];

        $checkValues = [
            ":CUSTOMER" => $row2["CUSTOMER"],
            ":BODY" => $row2["BODY"],
            ":MTRL" => $row2["MTRL"],
            ":ATTR" => $row2["ATTR"],
        ];

        try{
            //Array will contain records that are expired
            $existingRslt = $checkExisting->execute($checkValues);
            $count3 = $checkExisting->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            //Array will contain records that are valid
            $existingVldRslt = $checkExistingValid->execute($checkValues);
            $count4 = $checkExistingValid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        }catch(PDOException $ex){
                echo "QUERY FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
        }

             // IF records do not exist, or records exist and today is after expiration date
            if(empty($count3) && empty($count4)){
                print_r("Inserting");
                if($row2["QUANTITY"] > $row2["STORES"]){
                    for($i=0; $i<$row2["STORES"]; $i++){     
                        try{
                            $insertRslt = $insert->execute($values);
                        }catch(PDOException $ex){
                            echo "QUERY THREE FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }elseif($row2["QUANTITY"] < $row2["STORES"]){
                    for($i=0; $i<$row2["QUANTITY"]; $i++){   
                        try{
                            $insertRslt = $insert->execute($values);
                        }catch(PDOException $ex){
                            echo "QUERY THREE FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }elseif(!empty($count3)){
                print_r("Inserting");
                if($row2["QUANTITY"] > $row2["STORES"]){
                    for($i=0; $i<$row2['STORES']; $i++){
                        try{
                            $insertRslt = $insert->execute($values);
                        }catch(PDOException $ex){
                            echo "QUERY FOUR FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }elseif($row2["QUANTITY"] < $row2["STORES"]){
                    for($i=0; $i<$row2["QUANTITY"]; $i++){   
                        try{
                            $insertRslt = $insert->execute($values);
                        }catch(PDOException $ex){
                            echo "QUERY FOUR FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }elseif(!empty($count4)){
                print_r("updating");
                if($row2["QUANTITY"] > $row2["STORES"]){
                    for($i=0; $i<$row2['STORES']; $i++){
                        try{
                            $updateRslt = $update->execute($values);
                        }catch(PDOException $ex){
                            echo "QUERY FIVE FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }elseif($row2["QUANTITY"] < $row2["STORES"]){
                    for($i=0; $i<$row2['QUANTITY']; $i++){
                        try{
                            $updateRslt = $update->execute($values);
                        }catch(PDOException $ex){
                            echo "QUERY FIVE FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
         }    

?>
```

EDIT:

The main idea is this - If I have 10 locations and I place an order for 10 of a sku today, another order for 30 of that sku tomorrow and another for 20 of that sku the day after and the script gets run on that last day.......It's going to capture all 3 orders. A total of 60 skus, but at the end of the script I should only have 10 records for that sku.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly the logic of what you are doing, but maybe you can try  1/ Get your order -> use some PHP logic to know what you need to insert, update, etc. -> use your script to insert / update with the result you get OR 2/ Create ONE big query according to your order and execute it ONCE -> $sql = "Query1; Query2; ...; QueryX;" -> bindParam -> exectute -> this way each query should be executing in good order

Comment: I think that makes sense, and I know the logic is a little weird here. Here's a question: could I take :INVOICE and put that in an array and then do a foreach loop around the whole thing maybe? 
What I have now works as far as inserting, but the updates get missed if the select happens to have the rows that would need to be updated

Comment: The main problem is about the date right? For example if J1 you have a product that expire J2 and you make your request J3 the product will be "expired" even if when the order came it was not? Or somehting like that?

Comment: But for me to be sure to get all your data insert / update in good order : 1/ You get ALL your order you need to use. 2/ You loop through each order and use your logic to build your query. 3/ You execute all at once. So it should look like this basically 1/`$orders = "SELECT...->bindParam->execute->fetchAll"`; 2/ `$sql = ""; foreach($orders as order) { // use your logic and update $sql with $sql .= "request"; }` 3/ Execute $sql

Comment: Ok thank you, I tried a foreach last night and it seemed to do too many loops for each order so my logic was probably off. I'm going to try this again and see what results I can get, thanks!

Comment: Maybe there is a better solution for your problem, but your know what you want to achieve better than I do ! But still, treating your order one after each other in the good order should do the job, good luck !